# Obtain the Microsoft ID which was used to sign in to Store

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

I am developing a Universal Windows Platform app using Unity3D. I have in-app purchasing working using Windows.ApplicationModel.Store. The function CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync automatically shows a dialog asking the user to sign in to the Store to complete the purchase.

My app needs to store some user-related data locally, so I need some way to identify the user. Ideally, I would like to be able to access the same Microsoft ID which is used to sign in to the Store, so the user only has to suffer sign-in once. If the user manually signs out of the Store, my app will detect this and ask them to sign in again.

- On startup, check whether the user is already signed in to the Store. If not, prompt them to sign in.
- On choosing to purchase an item, if the user already signed in to the Store, continue with that account; if not, prompt the user to sign in.
- On the user manually signing out of the Store, show a warning, and prompt them to sign in again.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done? If not, what other options are there?

As far as I can tell, Web Account Manager (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager) sign-in is separate from Store sign-in; it can't be used to retrieve the Microsoft ID which was used to sign in to the Store. (Or am I wrong about this?)

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps take use of the [Windows.System.User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.user) and its NonRoamableId-property. NonRoamableId presents your app user on on device, meaning if the user installs the app on an another computer, the id will change.

Without completely knowing your requirements (why you want user to sign in if she signs out?) one another option could be to store the required data into [roaming or local settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data). With roaming settings, even if the user changes her computer, you can access the settings which your app has saved.

Or maybe you could store the data into user's Onedrive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately, Windows.System.User doesn't seem to give information about the account used to sign in to the Microsoft Store.